# Understanding the differences between auto_arima and SARIMAX predictions

Tags: python, time-series, statsmodels, arima

I would like to better understand the differences between the results obtained with the SARIMAX function and the auto_arima function.

In particular, I would like to understand.

0. why the two models show different results despite having the same order, using the same method and the same number of iterations.
   (I had found a post that talked about the use of different optimization methods that could be used by the two functions but I cannot find it again)
1. whether there is a specific reason why the pattern obtained with SARIMAX looks like a simple repetition of a pattern while the one obtained with aouto_arima seems to fit the data better.
2. why the model obtained with auto_arima has a null initial region. While SARIMAX does not.
3. I can improve the pattern obtained with SARIMAX library while keeping the same order.

I used the AirPassengers dataset present on Kaggle.
https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/rakannimer/air-passengers/data

I first addressed the issue of stationarity in the dataset, although I’ve left out the specifics of the Augmented Dickey-Fuller test for brevity. I then partitioned the dataset into a training set and a test set. To determine the optimal model order, I utilized the auto_arima library. This optimal order was subsequently applied in the SARIMAX library for model fitting. Lastly, I evaluated and compared the two models both visually and quantitatively using the Mean Squared Error (MSE) and Mean Absolute Error (MAE) on the test set.

These are my results:

DATASET
[image]

FORCAST
[image]

```py
import pandas as pd
from pmdarima.model_selection import train_test_split
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from statsmodels.tsa.statespace.sarimax import SARIMAX
from pmdarima import auto_arima
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
import warnings
#warnings.filterwarnings("ignore") #ignor all warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", module="statsmodels")# ingnor statsmodels warnings
import os
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from sklearn.metrics import mean_absolute_error

#iditialize dataframe
df = pd.read_csv("AirPassengers.csv")
df['Month'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Month'])
df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
df.set_index('Month', inplace=True)


#REMOVE STATIONARITY

#log transform
df['y_log'] = np.log(df['#Passengers']) 

#diff 1
df['y_diff1'] = df['y_log'] - df['y_log'].shift(1)

# Create an imputer object that replaces NaN values with the mean of the column
imputer = SimpleImputer(missing_values=np.nan, strategy='mean')

# Perform the imputation 
df['y_diff1'] = imputer.fit_transform(df['y_diff1'].values.reshape(-1, 1))

#diff 2
df['y_diff2'] = df['y_diff1'] - df['y_diff1'].shift(1)
# Create an imputer object that replaces NaN values with the mean of the column

# Perform the imputation 
df['y_diff2'] = imputer.fit_transform(df['y_diff2'].values.reshape(-1, 1))

# DATASET PLOT
fig, axs = plt.subplots(4, figsize=(12, 9))

# Plot dataser
axs[0].plot(df.index, df['#Passengers'], label='Original', color='blue')
axs[0].legend()
axs[0].grid(True)
axs[0].set_title("Original AirPassengers")
#log transform
axs[1].plot(df.index, df['y_log'], label='log', color='blue')
axs[1].legend()
axs[1].grid(True)
axs[1].set_title("log transform AirPassengers")

axs[2].plot(df.index, df['y_diff1'], label='diff1', color='blue')
axs[2].legend()
axs[2].grid(True)
axs[2].set_title("AirPassengers log and diffx1")

axs[3].plot(df.index, df['y_diff2'], label='diff2', color='blue')
axs[3].legend()
axs[3].grid(True)
axs[3].set_title("AirPassengers log and diffx2")
#adjust subplot spacing
plt.subplots_adjust(left=None, bottom=None, right=None, top=None, wspace=0.5, hspace=0.5)
plt.show()

# Split train test set
train, test = train_test_split(df['y_diff2'], train_size=0.8)
split_point = int(len(df) * 0.8)

#AUTO_ARIMA MODEL
# Fit the auto ARIMA model to the training data
model_autoarima = auto_arima(train, seasonal=True, m=12, method='lbfgs', maxiter=100,
                   max_D=1,
                   max_d=1,
                   max_P=1,
                   max_p=1,
                   max_Q=1,
                   max_q=1,
                   start_D=0,
                   start_d=0,
                   start_P=0,
                   start_p=0,
                   start_Q=0,
                   start_q=0)
model_autoarima.fit(train)

# parameters
print(f"Chosen order: {model_autoarima.order}")
print(f"Chosen seasonal order: {model_autoarima.seasonal_order}")

# predictions for the training and testing sets
train_pred_autoarima = model_autoarima.predict_in_sample()
test_pred_autoarima = model_autoarima.predict(n_periods=len(test))
# Combine the predictions
pred_autoarima = np.concatenate((train_pred_autoarima, test_pred_autoarima))

#SARIMAX MODEL
# Fit the model with the best parameters
model_SARIMAX = SARIMAX(train, order=model_autoarima.order, seasonal_order=model_autoarima.seasonal_order, method='lbfgs')
results = model_SARIMAX.fit(maxiter=100, method = "lbfgs")
# Get the forecast
pred_SARIMAX = results.get_forecast(steps=len(df))
pred_mean_SARIMAX = pred_SARIMAX.predicted_mean

#MSE AND MAE EVALUATION
mse_sarimax = mean_squared_error(df['y_diff2'][split_point:], pred_mean_SARIMAX[split_point:])
mse_autoarima = mean_squared_error(df['y_diff2'][split_point:], pred_autoarima[split_point:])

mae_sarimax = mean_absolute_error(df['y_diff2'][split_point:], pred_mean_SARIMAX[split_point:])
mae_autoarima = mean_absolute_error(df['y_diff2'][split_point:], pred_autoarima[split_point:])

print("testset evaluation")
print(f"autoarima mse:{mse_autoarima}, mae:{mae_autoarima}")
print(f"SARIMAX mse:{mse_sarimax}, mae:{mae_sarimax}")

# FINAL PLOT
fig, axs = plt.subplots(3, figsize=(12, 9))

# Plot the observed values
axs[0].plot(df.index[:split_point], df['y_diff2'][:split_point], label='Training', color='blue')
axs[0].plot(df.index[split_point:], df['y_diff2'][split_point:], label='Testing', color='green')
axs[0].legend()
axs[0].grid(True)
axs[0].set_title("Original AirPassengers data log-scaled and differentiated 2 times")

# Plot the SARIMAX predictions
axs[1].plot(df.index[:split_point], pred_mean_SARIMAX[:split_point], label='Training', color='blue')
axs[1].plot(df.index[split_point:], pred_mean_SARIMAX[split_point:], label='Testing', color='green')
axs[1].legend()
axs[1].grid(True)
axs[1].set_title(f"Forcast using SARIMAX {model_autoarima.order} {model_autoarima.seasonal_order} ")

# Plot the auto_arima predictions
axs[2].plot(df.index[:split_point], pred_autoarima[:split_point], label='Training', color='blue')
axs[2].plot(df.index[split_point:], pred_autoarima[split_point:], label='Testing', color='green')
axs[2].legend()
axs[2].grid(True)
axs[2].set_title(f"Forcast using auto_arima {model_autoarima.order} {model_autoarima.seasonal_order} ")

#adjust subplot spacing
plt.subplots_adjust(left=None, bottom=None, right=None, top=None, wspace=0.5, hspace=0.5)
plt.show()
```